Order of $\mathbb{E}[ \max_i |x_i + z_i| - \max_i |z_i|]$
Let $z_1, \dots, z_n$ be iid standard Normal, and let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Put $\|u\|_\infty = \max_i |u_i|$.
Define
$$
F(x) = \mathbb{E}\Big[\|x + z\|_\infty - \|z\|_\infty\Big]
$$
If $\|x\|_\infty \geq 2 \mathbb{E} \|z\|_\infty  = \Theta(\sqrt{\log n})$, then we clearly have $F(x) = \Theta(\|x\|_\infty)$. In fact, we easily see:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\|x\|_\infty \leq F(x) \leq \|x\|_\infty \quad \mbox{if} \quad \|x\|_\infty \geq 2 \mathbb{E} \|z\|_\infty.
$$
Thus, the question is now what happens when $\|x\|_\infty \ll \mathbb{E} \|z\|_\infty$. In this case, can one develop a sharp, up to multiplicative constants independent of dimension, approximation to $F(x)$?

I suspect no good general bounds are possible without saying something about the structure of $x$. If all entries of $x$ are the same, then $F(x) \asymp |x|\infty$, but if $x$ has a single large entry then $F(x) \ll |x|\infty$.

Is that true? I would still expect $F$ to behave quadratically near the origin, so I am wondering if the relation $F(x \mathbf{1}_n) \asymp |x|$ is really true for all $x$?

There's two ways to see that such quadratic behavior has to arise. First, consider the one-dimensional case, then it is clear that $F(x) \asymp \min{|x|, |x|^2}$. Secondly, for general $n$, note that if $|x|\infty \ll (\log n)^{-1/2}$, then with high probability $|x + g|\infty = |x_i + g_i|$ and $|g|_\infty = |g_i|$--the maximal coordinate is the same, and hence such quadratic behavior comes from the one-dimensional case again.

Fair enough, I was considering the regime where $1 \lesssim |x|_\infty \ll \sqrt{\log n}$. Do you agree that in that (wide) range, the behavior will depend on the structure of $x$?

Since we know that $E|Z|_\infty\sim \sqrt{\log n}$, the first easy case is if  $|x|_\infty=o( \sqrt{\log n})$. In that case,
$E |x+z|_\infty \sim E|z|_\infty$ in the sense that the ratio goes to $1$ asymptotically. This follows from  the bounds
$$ |z|_\infty-|x|_\infty\leq |z+x|_\infty\leq |z|_\infty+|x|_\infty.$$
In particular, trivially $\Omega(|x|_\infty/n)\leq |F(x)|\leq|x|_\infty$, which can’t be improved (consider the case of all coordinates constant for the upper bound, and of $x$ possessing a single non-zero coordinate for the lower bound).
So the only interesting regime (which maybe you do not care about)  is when $|x|_\infty\sim c\sqrt{\log n}$ where $c\in (0,\infty)$. In that case, $F(x)/E|z|_\infty$ depends on  the empirical measure $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{x_i/\sqrt{\log n}}$: If it is close to a non-degenerate probability measure, say $\mu$, then the ratio may be non-zero asymptotically. One can write a reasonably accurate expression as function of $\mu$. On the other hand if $\mu=\delta_0$ then only the infinity norm of $x$ enters in the ratio, and only if it larger than $E|z|_\infty$.
If one wants more accurate bounds on $F$, one needs to make assumptions on the empirical measure of the entries of $x$, with appropriate scaling.

In the case that $|x|\infty \ll \mathbb{E} |z|\infty$, from your argument, is it clear what the additive gap $\mathbb{E}|x + z|\infty - \mathbb{E} |z|\infty$ looks like? I am not sure that I understood.

Sorry, there was a stupid typo, corrected. The absolute value of the difference you ask about is bounded by $|x|_\infty$, which is of lower order than the leading term. It is not clear from your question what kind of result you look for.

When you say the bound "cannot be improved", what you mean, I guess is that if you have a bound depending only on the infinity norm of $x$, then this cannot be improved. My question is whether or not it is possible to have a more precise characterization of $F(x)$, for instance near the origin. A Taylor expansion would indicate that for $x$ close enough to $0$ we should have $F(x) \asymp |x|2^2/n$. On the other hand we know for $|x|\infty \gtrsim \sqrt{\log n}$, that $F(x) \asymp |x|_\infty$. Can a more precise characterization be obtained?

I wrote what I know. If the normalized empirical measure converges to mu, one can improve, but in general, I don't think so. For example, if $|x|\infty=\epsilon \sqrt{2 \log n}$ I do not think your $F$ is proportional to $|x|\infty$. Indeed, the number of coordinates larger than $(1-\epsilon) \sqrt{2\log n}$ is of order $n^{2\epsilon}$ and  thus $F\sim n^{2\epsilon -1}\sqrt{\log n}$. If  x has only one entry equal to 1, and all other entries 0, you claim that $F\sim 1/n$, but I actually think it is $e^{c\sqrt{\log n}}/n$, so I guess I am saying that I do not believe your Taylor argument.

I never claimed that for such $x$ that $F(x) \asymp 1/n$, rather I am saying that $\nabla^2 F(0) = \alpha_n I_n$ where $\alpha_n \asymp 1/n$. Additionally $\nabla f(0) = 0$. Hence, if $|x|_2$ is small enough (sorry, I haven't had the chance to calculate the third derivatives of $F$ to quantify this) then we should have $F(x) \asymp |x|_2^2/n$.
